# Unbounded linear functional $f(x)=\|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Assume $f$ is an **unbounded** linear functional on a real linear normed space $X$. How to prove that there exists $x\in X, x\neq 0$ such that

$$f(x)=\|x\|$$

Comment: @user334639 It's vacuously true if the space is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $f$ is unbounded, there exists $v\in X$ such that $f(v) > \Vert v \Vert$. Choose $w\in X \setminus \langle v \rangle$ (this is possible as the the space needs to be infinite dimensional to admit an unbounded functional) such that $f(w)<0 < \Vert w \Vert$. Then the function $$g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ g(t) = f(tv + (1-t)w) - \Vert tv + (1-t)w \Vert$$

is continuous (the restriction of $f$ to the finite-dimensional space generated by $v,w$ is continuous) and thus by the intermediate value theorem exists a $t_0\in (0,1)$ such that $g(t_0)=0$. Then $x= t_0v + (1-t_0)w$ does the job.

Comment: Oh, of course, for $f$ to be unbounded the space has to be infinite dimensional! I suggest adding that to the furst line of your answer.
[+1] for you, and next time I will leave a comment instead of answering :-)

Comment: @gerw thank you for catching this. I was careless.

Comment: @user334639 Is it clear this way? Or do I need to say more?

Comment: It's great. Thanks